# SquidGuard Patch (LDAP parsing error)

Tags: ldap, openldap, squid

I have been trying deal with LDAP for my Kerberos Authentication. I have successfully run Kerberos Authentication for Squid and SquidGuard using LDAP (AD). It's working well aside from the user filter function.

squidGuard.log shows the error:

```
Added LDAP source: internal%5csquidusertest
```

I have bump on this articlet: http://gotoanswer.stanford.edu/?q=SquidGuard+-+Ldap+doesnt+filter+users

But the hyperlink is no longer working as when you try going to the the main login page, it won't give the ability to register (page is not loading).

I wonder if someone has the copy of that patch.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As I check the compiled package for Debian Wheezy, I can see that the package for squidguard already includes the patch. It might be something on the configuration of my squidguard file.